# Why is the method of an Object stored to chrome.storage.sync not a function when retrieved?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm storing a Timer object into `chrome.storage.sync`. When I retrieve the Timer object and try to call one of its methods, `countdown()`, the method no longer exists:

```
  let clock = new Timer(1);
  let key = "myKey";
  chrome.storage.sync.set({[key]: clock});
  chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function(items){
    items[key].countdown();
  });
```

Chrome devTools says: "Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: items[key].countdown is not a function."

Comment: Why are you storing this into `storage.sync`? Is it really something you expect to synchronize across different machines linked to the same profile? It certainly does not appear to be something where that is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly store functions in [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage).

The documentation for [StorageArea.set()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#method-StorageArea-set) is quite explicit [emphasis mine]:

> Primitive values such as numbers will serialize as expected. **Values with a `typeof` `"object"` and `"function"` will typically serialize to `{}`**, with the exception of Array (serializes as expected), Date, and Regex (serialize using their String representation).

This appears to be a subset of [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/JSON) (JSON would serialize an Object composed of primitives just fine). However, even if it was a complete JSON implementation, it still would not be storing functions: "JSON does not natively represent more complex data types like functions, regular expressions, dates, and so on."

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who also landed on this question and haven't figured out the alternative solution to access a function from multiple places (without using `chrome.storage`), you can opt for [Message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/messaging/) between the place where the function meant to be used and the place it is created.

The above example could be roughly rewritten as:

In the script where the function was meant to be called:

```
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({startCountdown: true}, null);
```

In the current script:

```
      let clock = new Timer(1);
      let key = "myKey";
      chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
        if (message.startCountdown === true) {
            clock.countdown();
        };
      });
```